# How to define a root soap service in wsdl

Tags: java, soap, wsdl, apache-axis

In wsdl file, I am currently defining a service like:

```
<service name="test">
```

Then I can call API by sending request to localhost:port/test

What if i want to call API by sending reqeust to localhost:port or "localhost:port/"?

How to define the service? I tried:

```
<service name="/"> and <service name="">
```

It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Endpoint address:

[SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9807382/what-is-a-web-service-endpoint)

[Endpoint address](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733749(v=vs.110).aspx)

[Specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/WD-ws-addr-wsdl-20041208/)