# What is meant by an API Endpoint?

Tags: api

I am currently reading the documentations of [AlchemyAPI](http://www.alchemyapi.com/api/calling-the-api/). In the docs, they have used the term called "API Endpoint" and I am not able to figure out its corresponding meaning and explanation.

Any clarification in this regard would be very helpful to me.
Thanks.

Comment: see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9807382/what-is-a-web-service-endpoint

Comment: Web Service endpoint and API endpoint are more or less the same?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In HTTP/REST/etc API vernacular, an 'endpoint' typically refers to the URL for a single resource or operation. It is sometimes referred to in combination with the HTTP method used to access the URL.

Basically, it's the URL you access to get some data or take an action via the API.

Comment: Thanks..!That was halpful enough:)

Answer (score 3):

The endpoint is a web service, defined by a WSDL file

Microsoft use the term endpoint in different context. Check this for **[reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181835%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)**.

**For example:-** From the [wiki source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Services_Description_Language#Objects_in_WSDL_1.1_.2F_WSDL_2.0);-

> **ENDPOINT** Defines the address or connection point to a Web service. It
>   is typically represented by a simple HTTP URL string.

Comment: Why a downvote????? It is a request to all the downvoters to please leave a comment if anything is wrong in my answer. So that I can improve it :)

Comment: It's very unlikely it's referring to a SOAP service using a WSDL file. So your answer is too narrow.

Comment: @RunscopeAPITools:- I have just taken that as an example. I have also mentioned that *Microsoft use the term endpoint in different context.* And also attached a link for that

Comment: @RunscopeAPITools:- Hope that makes more sense now???

Comment: @RunscopeAPITools:- As for another example in the context of a REST endpoint, the endpoint would contain the requisite GET, PUT, POST and DELETE methods (as applicable). So I think I dont deserve your downvote Sir!!! :(

Comment: @RahulTripathi
Thanks..!That was helpful:)
+1 from my side

Comment: @phoenix:- You are welcome.!!! :) Although I ended up getting downvotes :(

Comment: @RahulTripathi
Dude, you have 14.6K, cheer up..!:p