# What is meant by Service End Point in Web Services? (not Definition but in real time scenario)

Tags: java, web-services, soap, amazon-web-services, wsdl

Actually I am new to web services So when i goggled about Web services lot of stuff is available but even though i am not able to get what is Service Endpoint is for?

Please help me out with a real time example

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9807382/what-is-a-web-service-endpoint

Comment: See this simple example
http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx?wsdl

In layman terms at any endpoint adding "?wsdl" gives you wsdl definition.
Here endpoint is "tempconvert" (or the complete URI) and operations are CelsiusToFahrenheit and FahrenheitToCelsius

Comment: The endpoint is the providing webservice application accessable over an URL ;) So it is what you are calling when using a webservice. But webservice is not equals webservice. Its an overall term for alot of different implementations and protocolls like SOAP or simple RESTFul Webservices etc.