# What is a Django endpoint?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

I have made a Django/jQuery/JS Tug O' War app in which users button mash their specific key in attempts to pull the HTML `<img>` tag all the way to their side of the screen. When a user wins, The Game/Player model fields are updated and the game starts over. Some of those fields are total amount of key presses it took to win the game, who won/lost, and how many wins/losses each player has.

The project I am working on asks that I *create a new Django **endpoint** for leaderboards* that display some simple game statistics.

***What is a Django endpoint?***

Is it just a fancy word for making a normal leader board? Or am I suppose to do something special? They suggest that I use *Mustache* while making it (can't find much of an explaination about what that is either).

I cannot seem to find relevant information on Stack Overflow or the interwebs. At this point I have been searching for an answer for about 2 hours.

***Here is a link to the project instructions..***

[Tug O' War](https://gist.github.com/himleyb85/2c3f5b02003432d985dc)

Comment: This may help: [What is a web service endpoint?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9807382/what-is-a-web-service-endpoint) Also, [`mustache` tag info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/mustache/info).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems they expect to create an API to send data to javascript, then using a templating engine like `mustache`, you create a leader page.

The master keyword here is : **ajax**.

> Display the leaderboards on the bottom of your game page. Use **AJAX** to load each leaderboard on game start. It should update when the game is finished, and the last game played should be present if applicable.

When someone need you to do a work using ajax, that means you need to server data only from the server and handle remains in UI.