# Get Api end points from wsdl file

Tags: api, soap, wsdl, wcf-endpoint

I'm trying to consume a commercial soap Api. I know their wsdl file but did not have any api endpoints to make request. I have searched on internet about how to get api endpoints from wsdl file but did not succeed. the wsdl file location is  http://cbs.zong.com.pk/reachcwsv2/corporatesms.svc?wsdl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9807382/what-is-a-web-service-endpoint) the end point url is obtained by removing the `?wsdl` from the path to wsdl

So WSDL is: http://cbs.zong.com.pk/reachcwsv2/corporatesms.svc?wsdl
then End-point is: http://cbs.zong.com.pk/reachcwsv2/corporatesms.svc

---

More accurately, the endpoint is defined in WSDL file by address `<address/>` tag as below. It could be different from what you get by just removing `?wsdl` suffix from URL, but most often thats not the case.

```html
<wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_ICorporateCBS" binding="tns:BasicHttpBinding_ICorporateCBS">
<soap:address location="http://cbs.zong.com.pk/ReachCWSv2/CorporateSMS.svc"/>
</wsdl:port>
```

Comment: @HaseebMazharRanga I had to update my answer after your response. SOAPUI will parse WSDL file for <address/> tag and use this and endpoint. Using SOAPUI would thus more accurately return the WSDL endpoint.

Comment: sorry, yes in some case removing ?wsdl would help but here no doing zong has a fix for that. i used the follow code got connection error. which is different problem all together. <?php 
$url ='https://cbs.zong.com.pk/reachcwsv2/corporatesms.svc?wsdl';
$client = new SoapClient($url,array("trace"=>1,"exception" => 0));
$result=$client->GetAccountSummary(array('obj_GetAccountSummary'=>array('loginId'=>'923331234567','loginPassword'=>'Mypassword')));
echo "<pre>" . var_dump($result) . "</pre><hr>";