# Get the URIs being used in SOAP UI project

Tags: soapui

How do we get all the URIs that are being used in requests for a SOAP UI project?

I tried out various options that are available under various menus of SOAP UI but did not find a solution. Not much help is available on google as well.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35289601/get-api-end-points-from-wsdl-file

Comment: The project file is an XML file. You can just seartch for `<con:soapui-project  rootPart`

Answer (score 0):

You can add a groovy testStep inside your testCase and try with the following code.

It takes the `project` and iterates over each testStep in the different testCases inside testSuites, getting the `Endpoint` property for each one.

```java
    def prj = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project
    prj.testSuites.each { namets, ts ->
        ts.testCases.each { nametc, tc ->
            tc.testSteps.each { nametstp, tstp ->
                log.info tstp.getPropertyValue('Endpoint')
            }
        }
    }
```

`Endpoint` property contains the URL used to invoke the service, however note that not all testSteps has `Endpoint` property, e.g groovy testStep or properties testStep, for this cases `null` is returned.