# Difference between a server and endpoint?

Tags: endpoint

According to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9807382/what-is-a-web-service-endpoint), the endpoint is the URL where your service can be accessed by a client application.

But, it sounds to me like a kind of server. In that case, an endpoint will be always an URL? what is the difference between an endpoint and a server?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An endpoint is a URL which allows you to access a (web) service running on a server. A server(program) may actually host multiple such services exposing them through different endpoint.

e.g. To access twitter search API, https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json is the endpoint. But the same server also has another endpoint https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate for authentication. Both the endpoints are hosted on the same server which runs on a machine with domain name `twiter.com`

Answer (score 1):

server is something who host your side/data or run multiple services, like php, mysql, etc

end point is where something points like we say end point of phpmyadmin, and might be its a end point of some api.

```
api.example.com/getusers
```