# How do I expose the service written in Java for all platforms?

Tags: java, api, architecture, client-server, system

I have an "AutoComplete" server written in java. Its a http(s) server  which accepts protobuf . Currently I have a written a thick desktop  client which uses this service to populate its textbox with  autosuggestions. I intend to make this service generic, so that it can  be used by other platforms. How do i go about it ? If i release proto  definitions it will probably tie it up to 3-4 languages only. If I  release a client jar , it will restrict it to Java. Any suggestion from  API/system designers is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you considerd exposing it as a Webservice?

Comment: Shall i redesign the whole thing a ReST server? Can you please elaborate, any hints would be useful .

Comment: What's to prevent you from providing all options? If the system works, all you need to do is provide the documentation(s) and optionally any existing libraries you may have.

Comment: @Kayaman I thought that it might restrict the target audience to a certain limit . But i will do that too, will release it with proper documentations and libraries.

Answer (score 2):

You can expose it as a [Webservice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service).

From the Wikipedia page:

> A Web service is a method of communication between two electronic devices over a network. It is a software function provided at a network address over the Web with the service always on as in the concept of utility computing. The W3C defines a Web service generally as
>   a software system designed to support interoperable machine-to-machine interaction over a network.

There are two types of Webservices:

1- [SOAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP) Webservices.

2- [REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) Webservices.

All programming languages provide methods for Creating and Consuming Websevices.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226108/what-is-a-web-service-in-plain-english) Stackoverflow thread provides good explanation of Webservices.

Answer (score 1):

A web service is a collection of open protocols and standards used for exchanging data between applications or systems. Software applications written in various programming languages and running on various platforms can use web services to exchange data over computer networks like the Internet in a manner similar to inter-process communication on a single computer. This interoperability (e.g., between Java and Python, or Windows and Linux applications) is due to the use of open standards.([Reference](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/webservices/what_are_web_services.htm))

REST stands for Representational State Transfer, which is an architectural style for networked hypermedia applications, it is primarily used to build Web services that are lightweight, maintainable, and scalable. A service based on REST is called a RESTful service. REST is not dependent on any protocol, but almost every RESTful service uses HTTP as its underlying protocol.

For complete tutorial have a look at [RESTful Web Services](http://www.drdobbs.com/web-development/restful-web-services-a-tutorial/240169069)

For SOAP based services have a look at [SOAP webservice](http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/ws_soap_intro.asp)